# Why does my .getdate script work intermittently?

Tags: javascript

I have a website which displays the month and day of the user visiting. It works fine right now, but when I update my code, the .getdate script stops working.

I am not altering any part of the script-- even when I copy and paste the same code that is working right now and upload it as a new file, the script does not work. I am a beginner and self-taught, so perhaps this has a very simple solution.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
var d = new Date();
var n = month[d.getMonth()] +' '+ [d.getDate()];
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>
```

And here is how it is implemented in the code:

```
< h3 > today is < h3 id="date" >< /h3 >< h3 > and you can change the world< /h3 >< /h3 >
```

Again, as it is, the code is working on my website right now. However, any attempt to re-use the same code fails. It would stand to reason that I could copy and paste this code and it would achieve the same results. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Are there any errors in the console or network tab when it does not work?

Comment: I don't recommend using new Array() as it's slower and unnecessary :)

Comment: Your code doesn't actually do anything, it just defines a function.

Comment: Are you trying to nest `h3` tags?!

Comment: Are you actually calling the function anywhere with `myFunction()`?

Comment: Also `[d.getDate()]` works, but is almost certainly not what you intended. `[x]` creates a new array containing `x`, and the string concatenation will simply collapse the array again using `join`. I'd recommend taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552493/1715579) for some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the spaces that have snuck into the markup. Here is your snippet working. All I did was delete the spaces inside the tags.

```js
function myFunction() {
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
var d = new Date();
var n = month[d.getMonth()] +' '+ [d.getDate()];
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = n;
}
myFunction()
```

```html
<h3> today is <h3 id="date" ></h3><h3> and you can change the world</h3></h3>
```

But while we're here, you should really avoid this kind of low level operation on dates, and use the built in functions. You can do what you want with...

```
var formattedDate = new Date().toLocaleString({},{month:'long', day:'numeric'})
```

...and it's automatically translated into the language of your user.